# Qt Android - Error while deploying project

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

I'm trying to develop application on android device through Qt creator. I've updated NDK & SDK path from Projects-> Manage kits ...-> Options -> Android Tabs.

[image]

I got this an error while deploying :

```
15:50:17: Packaging error: Command "sdk path/platform-tools/adb.exe -s deviceSerial pull /system/bin/asan/app_process D:/path/build-myApplicationName-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0-Debug/app_process" failed.Exit code: 1
```

I've deleted directory which made by old SDK , clean all and build again 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Try and run [`adb logcat`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) to look for any error messages that may be showing when you try to deploy your app.